# Python TCP Server Not Connecting

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, networking, tcp

Trying to create a TCP server, code stops running @ server.accept. I am a complete networking n00b not sure whats going wrong at all.

```
import socket
import threading

bind_ip = "0.0.0.0"
bind_port = 9999

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

server.bind((bind_ip, bind_port))

server.listen(5)

print(" [*] Listening on %s:%d" % (bind_ip, bind_port))

def handle_client(client_socket):
    request = client_socket.recv(1024)

    print("[*] Received: %s " % request)

    client_socket.send("ACK")

    client_socket.close()

while True:

    print("accepted")
    #break here 
    client, addr = server.accept()

    print("[*] Accepted connection from: %s:%d" % (addr[0], addr[1]))

    client_handler = threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(client,))
    client_handler.start()
```

Also having issues creating a UDP client

Comment: Are you even connecting to the server? A server only waits for connections, so if you are only running this program, it is expected that it hangs at `server.accept()`

Comment: from the docs.....`Wait for an incoming connection. Return a new socket representing the connection, and the address of the client.` The code doesnt stop. ITs waiting for a connection. If i take your code and run it then make a connection on port 9999 i get: `[*] Accepted connection from: 127.0.0.1:54234` and `[*] Received: b'SSH-2.0-PuTTY_Release_0.74\r\n' `

Comment: LOL I'm done sorry this code is from a work book Thank you